# How to optimize code for finding Amicable Pairs

Tags: optimization, number-theory

Please see the code I've used to find what I believe are all Amicable Pairs (n, m), n < m, 2 <= n <= 65 million. My code: http://tutoree7.pastebin.com/wKvMAWpT. The found pairs: http://tutoree7.pastebin.com/dpEc0RbZ.

I'm finding that each additional million now takes 24 minutes on my laptop. I'm hoping there are substantial numbers of n that can be filtered out in advance. This comes close, but no cigar: odd n that don't end in '5'. There is only one counterexample pair so far, but that's one too many: (34765731, 36939357). That as a filter would filter out 40% of all n.

I'm hoping for some ideas, not necessarily the Python code for implementing them.

Comment: Are you doing this for the Euler Project or any other contest?

Comment: @XML No. As an exercise in optimization. Up to now I worked at optimizing the function.

Comment: This is a very short snippet http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/math09/math09t1.htm

Comment: @belisarius: but no filters employed in finding those pairs? Anyway, very interesting site -- not only ch. 9!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article that summarizes all optimization techniques for **[finding amicable pairs](http://sech.me/ap/articles.html)**

with **[sample C++ code](https://github.com/SChernykh/Amicable)**

It finds all amicable numbers up to 10^9 in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int sumOfFactors(int );

int main(){
    int x, y, start, end;
    printf("Enter start of the range:\n");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    printf("Enter end of the range:\n");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    for(x = start;x <= end;x++){
        for(y=end; y>= start;y--){
            if(x == sumOfFactors(y) && y == sumOfFactors(x) && x != y){
                printf("The numbers %d and %d are Amicable pair\n", x,y);
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}

int sumOfFactors(int x){
    int sum = 1, i, j;
    for(j=2;j <= x/2;j++){
        if(x % j == 0)
            sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The asker mentioned that they were using Python - it would be better to respond with that language. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def findSumOfFactors(n):
    sum = 1
    for i in range(2, int(n / 2) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            sum += i
    return sum

start = int(input())
end = int(input())

for i in range(start, end + 1):
    for j in range(end, start + 1, -1):
        if i is not j and findSumOfFactors(i) == j and findSumOfFactors(j) == i and j>1:
            print(i, j)
```